# Doctrine relationship conditions

Tags: symfony, annotations, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a Symfony2 project with an existing database.

In the database there is different statuses, where each status has a type.
E.G

```
status  |  type  |  description
   C         O       Completed
   C         G       Cancelled
```

Now I have an order entity, which joins with status entity.
I only want join the orders where the status type is O.

My current model looks like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Statuses", inversedBy="orders")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="status", referencedColumnName="status")
 */
private $status;
```

How can I specify to join only on the type, so if an order has got a status of C, then I get the 'completed' status on the join and not the 'cancelled' one?

Unfortunately I can't make any changes to the database structure, as there is other apps dependant on the structure.